# Firebase Cloud Firestore codes

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I setted up everything of using Firebase with Android Application, and I succeeded in log in with google account ( which is the very first step ) 
My project planned to use Cloud Firestore for database, however, something seems to be wrong while I try to call the information from my firestore ( and yes I did create one). Here's how it goes.

```
  //I created at beginning
FirebaseUser user;
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionRefernce userColRef = db.collection("users");

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    // Followed the instructions from the Firebase Documents...
    // ....

     if(task.isSuccessful()){
                //This toast is shown
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OAuth completed, to user info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadUserInfo();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}



private void loadUserInfo(){

      user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

      *******// The problem seems to occur here! 
      // It would not do both if and else statement.*******

      userColRef.document(user.getUid()).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged In!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                dialog.dismiss();

                goMainActivity();


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No valid user, saving new user...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                saveUserInfo();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Is there any settings that is necessary to access the firestore besides creating one? I've done all the instructions but I can't debug my code. My mentor couldn't also.. please help  :( :(

Comment: Add an [onFailureListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).  Also, try setting `userColRef` and `db` after the user successfully logs in.

Comment: well the algorithm goes : check from google if it is the user -> give it to firebase -> checks if the user is in database -> if yes, log in / if not save it to database and log in // so how can it come after log in?

Comment: At the very least, add the `onFailedListener` to see why your `onSuccessListener` block isn't triggered.

Comment: What is really happening when you are using this code? Please responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo I just followed the instructions from firebase. It's not on the question but the in the code, the firebaseAuthWithGoogle first checks if its google user, and if it is, it passes to loadUserInfo, and in the loadUserInfo it is suppose to check the Firestore database of the linked firebase project.
It receives the currentUser and checks.

Comment: "It's not on the question" so what is it?

Comment: @AlexMamo  I meant the codes before those codes on the activity. It don’t think it really matters because it worked before I putted the codes in the question